# Broken markup during animation in Chrome (jsfiddle)

Tags: google-chrome, animation, markup

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HPm4a/).
If you open it in Chrome, select some elements and then deselect you'll see the problem:

[Problem with markup during animation in Chrome http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/3980/013m.png](http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/3980/013m.png)

Also `#selector` "jumps" at the end of hide-animation. This is only seen in Chrome. How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like a bug in `animate`. Removing the char from the box fixes the jitter. Either go with fixing `animate` or position an additional element within the `li` - http://jsfiddle.net/HPm4a/36/

Comment: And what if you click one really fast a couple times?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/XYwGa/1/

@Oskar Krawczyk, Remix with your styles :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the jitter at the end of the animation, but to fix the issue with them moving down, remove the `float: left` property of the `li` elements.

Comment: I wouldn't like to do that, because i have a lot of other elements (some kind of group headers) in `#selector` and they are positioned very well with `float: left`. If i remove `float`, i will have to append a lot of other redundant markup...